# A SQL query executed parallel unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

A SQL query with an estimated cost of 32 gets executed in parallel although the value for 'Cost Threshold for Parallelism' is set to 50.

This screenshot is taken from a SQL Server 2022CU10 server, but I saw the same behavior on SQL Server 2019.

Can anyone tell me why this query is executed in parallel?

**Query plan:**

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyuhurF_6

[image]

Steps to reproduce

1. set 'cost threshold for parallelism' to 50
2. create a test database and insert 1 million rows in a table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table_0
(
    A char(1),
    B char(1),
    C char(1),
    D char(1),
    E char(1),
    F char(1),
    G char(1),
    H char(1),
    I char(1),
    J char(1),
    K char(1),
    L char(1)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.table_0 (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L)
SELECT TOP (1000000) 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'
FROM sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2
```

3. execute the following query

```
SELECT
      [A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F],[G],[H],[I],[J],[K],[L]
FROM
      [dbo].[table_0]
ORDER BY 
    5, 3, 1, 8
```

Comment: This is probably something often misunderstood. The *executed query* has a cost threshold of 32, but the single threaded execution plan which would be evaluated *first*, will have exceeded 50, hence a parallel option was explored by the optimizer; What do you see if you use option `maxdop 1`?

Comment: @Stu, you are right executing this with maxdop 1 generates a plan with an estimated cost of 94.6. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In future you should add a link to the full query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: @Charlieface - That site currently appears to be down. It is easy to reproduce the plan by running the code in the Q anyway

Comment: Try https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 3):

When running a query, the optimizer will first explore a non-parallel plan option and evaluate the best found plan's cost. If the cost is below that set by the threshold then you're good to go and the single-threaded plan is used, however if the single-threaded plan's cost *exceeds* the threshold, it will explore *parallel* plans.

Assuming a parallel plan has a lower cost, the generated plan will be parallel and it is *this* cost you see on the actual plan, which indeed can be lower than the specified cost threshold for parallelism, which was only used as a threshold against that of the single-threaded plan (which was never used).

I tried a similar test on my local SQL Server instance and when forcing a serial plan the query cost is 94 whilst the parallel cost is 23 so with my cost threshold of 55 the optimizer chose the parallel plan, which is what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

I repro the same thing on my 2022 instance.

@Stu's answer explains why a parallel plan is considered in the first place.

But why is it costed cheaper than the serial plan and ultimately selected? Both plans have to scan the same table and sort the same amount of rows? Plus the parallel plan has the overhead of the parallelism itself.

[This is explained by Paul White here](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.html)

> When SQL Server costs a parallel plan, it generally reduces the CPU cost for a parallel iterator by a factor equal to the expected runtime DOP (degree of parallelism

I see the execution plans below for `DOP 1` and `DOP 4`

[image]

The per operator costs are below showing the expected scaling down for DOP 4 (and for the sort this apparently includes both IO and CPU cost)

| Operator Name | Cost Type | Serial | DOP 4 | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parallelism | CPU | N/A | 6.98037 |  |
|  | IO | N/A | 0 |  |
| Sort | CPU | 91.486 | 22.8715 | 25.00% |
|  | IO | 0.0112613 | 0.0028153 | 25.00% |
| Table Scan | CPU | 1.10016 | 0.27502 | 25.00% |
|  | IO | 2.01572 | 2.0158 | 100.00% |
| **Total** |  | **94.6131413** | **32.1455053** | **33.98%** |